# Cannot get cURL support enabled in PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, curl

cURL does not appear in phpinfo() and fails inside of PHP scripts even after ensuring the following:

- curl.so does exist in /usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so along with my other successfully working PHP modules.
- /usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so is the only place where curl.so is to be found on the system.
- extension=curl.so is uncommented in php.ini
- /etc/php/php.ini is the only place where php.ini is to be found on the system.
- I restarted my webserver several times.
- The phpinfo Configure Command shows: '--with-curl=shared'

However, the big blue block that shows "curl" settings (as typically found in phpinfo on other systems) is not appearing. Furthermore, function_exists('curl_init') returns false inside of PHP.

I must be missing something... But what?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please check if your phpinfo() output shows path of php.in as /etc/php/php.ini?

Comment: curl=shared means that it will be looking for curl's libraries as part of the system.  Have you made sure that curl and the curl libraries are installed at the system level?  Also, is the extension directory in your php.ini pointing at the right place?

Comment: @anubhava: Loaded Configuration File shows /etc/php/php.ini

Comment: @Charles: I installed curl and php-curl via the Arch Linux package manager: pacman -S curl and pacman -S php-curl and I also did this explicitly for all of their listed dependencies just in case something strange prevented them from resolving dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dl("curl.so");
```

Try this eventually even with the complete path to the library. And also check if this works on the commandline. If the .so should be incompatible to your PHP interpreter (or be otherwise corrupt), then you will not see any messages in the output from a phpinfo script. PHP fails otherwise silently if it was referenced from the php.ini. Any issues would only turn up on the console or in the Apache error log.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl()... The PHP docs at http://us2.php.net/dl say that "This function has been removed from some SAPI's in PHP 5.3."

Comment: Yes. Try it with the CLI version (for our testing purposes here). There it's still allowed.

Comment: Okay, I get this: PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: This is odd. Test `var_dump(function_exists("curl_init"));` in the CLI version.

Comment: I just tested and found that function_exists('curl_init') returns true when performed via the CLI.

Comment: So at least `curl.so` is working then. Try editing the complete library path into the php.ini `extension=` load directive.

Comment: Are you checking phpinfo() output from browser or command line? Please make sure you get same output from both channels.

Comment: I changed it to this in php.ini: extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so and restarted my webserver. It is experiencing the exact same symptoms in all tests.

Comment: If the .so plugins cannot be linked then PHP prints `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/...'` into the Apache `error.log`. Have a look.

Comment: That is not appearing anywhere in the error.log for the webserver. (I'm using Nginx, not Apache BTW, hope that isn't the problem, though I wouldn't imagine so..)

Comment: It would appear in the log anyway. But you should ensure that you really restarted the webserver. Just reloading the config wouldn't work. Best to reboot once.

Comment: There's not much else to debug with the php.ini, except to ensure that the `extension=` directive is really in the `[PHP]` section and not at the file bottom.

Comment: Unbelievable. I performed a soft reboot of the server and it worked instantly. Note to self: Never trust /etc/rc.d/nginx restart

Comment: For what it's worth: had the same problem once with an older Apache setup.

Comment: Many thanks! Now I have the fun task of isolating which of your suggestions actually solved the problem. :)